Why `.*` get an extra matches in js/python/perl but not in awk/sed/R?
When I replace .* with another string using regex, I got the following result:
In Linux sed, awk and perl:
echo -n 123 | sed 's/.*/456/g'
456
echo -n 123 | awk '{gsub(/.*/,"456");print}'
456
echo -n 123 | perl -pe 's/.*/456/g'
456456

In node.js:
> "123".replace(/.*/g,"456")
'456456'

In python:
>>> re.sub(".*","456","123")
'456456'

In R
> gsub(".*","456","123")
[1] "456"

Why are they different?

I believe this was fixed in Python recently.
